# Significance of boolean direct Output Fields declare (boolean direct, Fields fields)

Tags: apache-storm

Looking at the `OutputFieldsDeclarer` class, I see there is an overloaded method for `declare(...)` with a boolean flag `direct`.

If I use the method `declare(Fields fields)`, it sets this boolean flag as `false`.

I am not sure how Storm interprets this boolean field internally while processing with Spouts and Bolts .

Can somebody explain me the significance of this flag?

Answer (score 1):

If you declare a direct stream (ie, setting the flag to `true`), you need to
emit tuples via

```
collector.emitDirect(...)
```

methods (`collector.emit(...)` is not allowed for direct streams). Those
methods require to specify the consumer task ID that should receive the
tuple.

Furthermore, when connecting a consumer to a direct stream, you need to
specify

```
builder.setBolt(....).directGrouping("direct-emitting-bolt", "direct-stream-Id");
```

All other connection patterns are not allowed on direct stream.

Direct streams have the advantage, that you have fine-grained controlled
over the data distribution from producer to consumer. You can implement
any imaginable distribution pattern. Of course, direct streams are much
more difficult to handle. For example, you need to know the task IDs of
subscribed consumers (those can be looked up in the `TopologyContext`
provided via `Bolt.prepare`).